# Scala Listener/Observer

Tags: scala, listener, observer-pattern

Typically, in Java, when I've got an object who's providing some sort of notification to other objects, I'll employ the Listener/Observer pattern.

Is there a more Scala-like way to do this? Should I be using this pattern in Scala, or is there something else baked into the language I should be taking advantage of?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can still accumulate a list of callbacks, but you can just make them functions instead of having to come up with yet another single method interface.

e.g.

```
case class MyEvent(...)

object Foo { 
  var listeners: List[MyEvent => ()] = Nil

  def listen(listener: MyEvent => ()) {
    listeners ::= listener
  }

  def notify(ev: MyEvent) = for (l <- listeners) l(ev) 
}
```

Also read this [this somewhat-related paper](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/148043/files/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) if you feel like taking the red pill. :)

Comment: And you can extract this nicely into a `Publisher` trait.

Answer (score 18):

> Is there a more Scala-like way to do this?

Yes. Read the paper [Deprecating the Observer Pattern](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/148043/files/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) by Ingo Maier, Tiark Rompf, and Martin Odersky.

**Update 27-Apt-2015:** There is also a more recent [Deprecating the Observer Pattern with Scala.React](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/176887/files/DeprecatingObservers2012.pdf) by Maier and Odersky.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this?

Comment: @cdmckay `scala.swing` package in the standard library is based on it. See its examples and tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

```
trait Observer[S] {
     def receiveUpdate(subject: S);
}

trait Subject[S] {
     this: S =>
     private var observers: List[Observer[S]] = Nil
     def addObserver(observer: Observer[S]) = observers = observer :: observers

     def notifyObservers() = observers.foreach(_.receiveUpdate(this))
}
```

This snippet is pretty similar to what one would find in Java with some Scala features. This is from Dean Wampler's blog - http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2008/08/03/the-seductions-of-scala-part-i

This uses some Scala features such as generics as denoted by the [S], traits which are like Java interfaces but more powerful, :: to prepend an observer to the list of observers, and a foreach with the parameter using an _ which evaluates to the current observer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scala.collection.mutable.Publisher and scala.collection.mutable.Subscriber to create a pub/sub implementation

Comment: @ziggystar, and? What was your experience?

Comment: I think I didn't get it to work or it was annoying to use. I'm now using third party libraries or rolling my own.