# Implementing observer pattern

Tags: scala

I recently started learning Scala and started a little project to create a simple roguelike game. However, I'm stuck at trying to implement the observer pattern. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755647/879114) answer touches the subject, but I can't figure out how to make it work. Below is the code from the answer linked above. I'm mostly puzzled by the "**this: S =>**" part of the code, I suppose I should have some kind of a function there, but I'm not sure. I would like to have it return a tuple from the class that will extend the Subject trait.

```
trait Observer[S] {
 def receiveUpdate(subject: S);
}

trait Subject[S] {
 this: S =>
 private var observers: List[Observer[S]] = Nil
 def addObserver(observer: Observer[S]) = observers = observer :: observers

 def notifyObservers() = observers.foreach(_.receiveUpdate(this))
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See Steve's answer about the `self` type and for another code example.

Here is some sample code using an observer. The `ObservedAccount` is the `Subject` that is observed by an `AccountReporter` observer.

```
trait Observer[S] {
    def receiveUpdate(subject: S);
}

trait Subject[S] { 
    this: S =>
    private var observers: List[Observer[S]] = Nil
    def addObserver(observer: Observer[S]) = observers = observer :: observers

    def notifyObservers() = observers.foreach(_.receiveUpdate(this))
}

class Account(initialBalance: Double) {
    private var currentBalance = initialBalance
    def balance = currentBalance
    def deposit(amount: Double)  = currentBalance += amount
    def withdraw(amount: Double) = currentBalance -= amount
}

class ObservedAccount(initialBalance: Double) extends Account(initialBalance) with Subject[Account] {
    override def deposit(amount: Double) = {
        super.deposit(amount)
        notifyObservers()
    }
    override def withdraw(amount: Double) = {
        super.withdraw(amount)
        notifyObservers()
    }
}


class AccountReporter extends Observer[Account] {
    def receiveUpdate(account: Account) =
        println("Observed balance change: "+account.balance)
}
```

Let's see it in action:

```
scala> val oa = new ObservedAccount(100.0)
oa: ObservedAccount = ObservedAccount@3f947e20

scala> val ar = new AccountReporter
ar: AccountReporter = AccountReporter@6ea70a98

scala> oa.addObserver(ar)

scala> oa.deposit(40.0)
Observed balance change: 140.0

scala> oa.withdraw(40.0)
Observed balance change: 100.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on Brian's answer: I find it unnecessary to have a separate `Observer[S]` trait, simply `S => Unit` is good enough:

```
trait Subject[S] {
  this: S =>
  private var observers: List[S => Unit] = Nil
  def addObserver(observer: S => Unit) = observers = observer :: observers
  def notifyObservers() = observers.foreach(_.apply(this))
}

class Account(initialBalance: Double) {
  private var currentBalance = initialBalance
  def balance = currentBalance
  def deposit(amount: Double) = currentBalance += amount
  def withdraw(amount: Double) = currentBalance -= amount
}

class ObservedAccount(initialBalance: Double) extends Account(initialBalance)
  with Subject[Account] {

  override def deposit(amount: Double) = {
    super.deposit(amount)
    notifyObservers()
  }
  override def withdraw(amount: Double) = {
    super.withdraw(amount)
    notifyObservers()
  }
}

class AccountReporter {
  def receiveUpdate(account: Account) =
    println("Observed balance change: " + account.balance)
}

object Main extends App {
  println("start app")
  val oa = new ObservedAccount(100.0)
  val ar = new AccountReporter
  oa.addObserver(ar.receiveUpdate _)
  oa.deposit(40.0)
  oa.deposit(60.0)
  println("stop  app")
}


/**
      a copy paste observer pattern scala mini-app
      sbt run should produce:
      [info] Running app.Main
      start app
      Observed balance change: 140.0
      Observed balance change: 200.0
      stop  app
  */
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer a question with a question.  Have you read [your answer here](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.pdf) or [the more interesting answer here](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) and [here](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/176887)?  Someone should compile a reading list, if they haven't.  Did Coursera have a reading list?

Comment: I did take a look, but decided not to try something completely new to me for now :)

Answer (score 1):

this is a Scala self-type ( see http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124 ). It expresses a requirement that all concrete implementations of the trait Subject[S] must also conform to the type S. That is, every observable Subject[S] is itself an S.

This is reasonable for the Observer pattern -- it is the observable subject itself that should have registration and notify methods, so the subject consistent with an observer of S should itself be an S.